# Slide Menu jQuery/CSS Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've done everything I think is correct, yet i'm still facing the same issue.

When clicking the bootstrap Glyphicon icon, the menu doesn't slide/ease in like my code suggests.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong and why?

Heres the HTML:

```
<header>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify nav-toggle"></i>
    <nav class="main-navigation">
        <span class="nav-toggle">Close</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>        
</header>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
/* NAV MENU */

header {
    background-color: white;
    color: #0099ff;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a {
    color: #0099ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li {
    list-style: none;
}

.main-navigation {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #005c99;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.main-navigation .nav-toggle {
    right: 5%;
    top: 5%;
}
.main-navigation.open {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.main-navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
}

.main-navigation ul a:hover {
    background: #0099ff;
}
```

And heres the tiny bit of jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function(){
        $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can see it in action?

Comment: I'll be honest I'm struggling to get JSFiddle to work... :-/

Comment: I don't see jquery for the slider.

Comment: everything seems ok https://jsfiddle.net/r8n9q6vb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

Turns out it was a broken link/Mistype for my script.js

Thanks for everyone's help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvnkofnv/) and seems everything is working well.

Remember to load jQuery and last compiled Bootstrap javascript and css:

**jQuery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Bootstrap**

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Strange... I haven't changed the html, css, or jquery. I've added and removed your suggested links yet clicking the button still doesn't work.

Any additional ideas as to why this may be?

Comment: Is [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvnkofnv/) working for you? Are you getting any error in your browser console? I really don't know what more to say.

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I wasn't clear.

The Fiddles work, but the button doesn't do anything via my Live Preview from Brackets.

Comment: Try saving jQuery and Bootstrap (css/js) to your project folder. Then load locally and not from the CDN.

Comment: It is already currently installed locally.

Comment: No errors in the console? If not, I'm sorry but I think I can't help you with this. Hope you solve it :)